# Emulating method overloading in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, overloading

I am writing a math library in Objective-C (for fun) and and now I need some way to emulate C++-styled function overloading.

My intended look:

```
NSNumber *x = @(25);
CMVector *v = [CMVector vectorWithElements:@12, @14, @18, nil];
CMMatrix *m = [CMMatrix matrixWithRows:@[@12, @13, @0 ],
                                       @[@24, @26, @30],
                                       @[@0,  @0,  @1 ], nil];
CMMatrix *i = [CMMatrix identityMatrixWithRank:3];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", [x multiply:v], [x multiply:m], [m multiply: i], [v multiply:x]);
```

Is there any way implementing this?

Here is a possible way I came up, using a class to represent an overloaded function and encode argument names into class method names, like:

```
@interface CMMultiply : NSProxy

+ (NSNumber *)NSNumber:(NSNumber *)left NSNumber:(NSNumber *)right;
+ (CMVector *)NSNumber:(NSNumber *)left CMVector:(CMVector *)right;
+ (CMVector *)CMVector:(CMVector *)left NSNumber:(NSNumber *)right;
+ (CMVector *)CMVector:(CMVector *)left CMVector:(CMVector *)right;
+ (CMMatrix *)NSNumber:(NSNumber *)left CMMatrix:(CMMatrix *)right;
+ (CMMatrix *)CMMatrix:(CMMatrix *)left NSNumber:(NSNumber *)right;
+ (CMMatrix *)CMMatrix:(CMMatrix *)left CMMatrix:(CMMatrix *)right;

@end
```

and implement the overloaded method by create the encoded method name and call it.

Any better ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is my overloading logic:

```
@implementation NSObject (CMOverloading)

- (NSString *)overloadingClassName
{
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]); // Override this to handle class clusters
}

- (id)callOverloadedMethod:(Class)method withObject:(id)other
{
    NSString *methodName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:", [self overloadingClassName], [other overloadingClassName]];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);
    return objc_msgSend(method, selector, self, other);
}

@end
```

**EDIT 2**

The base class for the "overload library" is `NSProxy` so that users of the library cannot instantiate it.

**EDIT 3**

Implementation simplifying macros:

```
#define CMOverloadingMethod(_return, _left, _right) \
+ (_return *)_left:(_left *)left _right:(_right *)right

#define CMOverloadedMethod(_type, _object) \
return [self callOverloadedMethod:[_type class] withObject:(_object)]
```

An overloaded method still need a (simple) single implementation, here, directly in `NSObject`:

```
- (id)multiply:(id)right
{
    CMOverloadedMethod(CMMultiply, right);
}
```

and implementing it by `NSNumber`:

```
@implementation CMMultiply (NSNumber)

CMOverloadingMethod(NSNumber, NSNumber, NSNumber)
{
    return @([left doubleValue] * [right doubleValue]);
}

@end
```

Comment: Creating a class for each operation is crazy! If you really need operator overloading—and you should consider that carefully—one way would be to specify your method’s arguments as being of type `id`. Then you can use `isKindOfClass:` to decide exactly what you need to do with them.

Comment: @bdesham Well this "one class for each overload" is intended to be used with class categories so that different overloads can be added later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final design I used, resolving the types using reflection. I am still using classes as containers of overloaded functions, essentially using those container types as vtables:

```
#define CMOverloadingMethod(_return, _left, _right) \
+ (_return *)_left:(_left *)left _right:(_right *)right

#define CMOverloadedMethod(_type, _object) \
return [self callOverloadedMethod:[_type class] withObject:(_object)]

- (id)callOverloadedMethod:(Class)method withObject:(id)other
{
    Class thisClass = [self class];
    Class nextClass = [other class];
    Class methodClass = object_getClass(method);

    // Find the appropriate overload:
    Class thisClass2 = Nil;
    do
    {
        thisClass2 = thisClass;

        Class otherClass = nextClass;
        Class otherClass2 = Nil;
        do
        {
            otherClass2 = otherClass;
            SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(MSSTR(@"%@:%@:", NSStringFromClass(thisClass), NSStringFromClass(otherClass)));
            if (class_respondsToSelector(methodClass, selector))
                return objc_msgSend(method, selector, self, other);
            else
                otherClass = class_getSuperclass(otherClass);
        } while (otherClass != otherClass2 && otherClass && otherClass2);
        thisClass = class_getSuperclass(thisClass);
    } while (thisClass != thisClass2 && thisClass && thisClass2);

    [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Cannot resolve overloaded method in class %@ for objects typed %@ and %@.", NSStringFromClass(method), NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromClass([other class])];
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this syntax

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", [x multiply:v], [x multiply:m], [m multiply: i], [v multiply:x]);
```

you would have to implement a multiply method in each of your math classes (vector, matrix) and a category method on NSNumber. The problem is that you also want to be able to pass any argument and this is not supported in Objective-C (multiple methods with the same name, but different argument types).

Instead you could either take an id as argument and figure out the type at runtime or you would have to be more verbose:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", [x multiplyWithVector:v], 
                      [x multiplyWithMatrix:m],
                      [m multiplyWithMatrix:i],
                      [v multiplyWithScalar:x]);
```

But this is overly complicated and besides, implementing a math library like this would be quite slow.

Why don't you use simple structs and functions instead? That's been done numerous times and it works.

Comment: I said, for fun. For real deal I would rather go directly to GMP/MPFR or like.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C doesn't use a vtable like C++. It refers to methods using a string lookup, so you can't overload methods by parameters. Your best bet, then, is to use `id` to allow referring to any type of parameter. So your `multiply` method would look like this:

```
+ (id)multiplyLeft:(id)left right:(id)right;
```

Not the prettiest solution.

You could use categories, and then you'd have a solution that begins like this:

```
@interface NSObject (Math)

- (instancetype)multiply:(id)right;

@end

@implementation NSObject (Math)

- (instancetype)multiply:(id)right
{
    // Feel free to throw an exception here.
    return nil;
}

@end

@implementation NSNumber (Math)

- (instancetype)multiply:(id)right
{
    if ([right isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self integerValue] * [right integerValue]];
    }
    else
    {
    // Feel free to throw an exception here.
        return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Again, not a pretty solution but it allows you to write what you're after.

Good luck.

Comment: I am actually trying to implement a type-based vtable lookup on top of the string match.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use C++. Objective-C++ is pretty powerful. Clang now supports C++ 11. This is the kind of stuff C++ does very well, and intermixing the code of the two languages is pretty clean and easy.

Comment: I am sort of on the same page as [Linus Torvalds](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918) on C++, just flat out dislike, detest and hate it. So, no, I will stick to Objective-C or just pure C.

Comment: Oh boy, if Linus says it's bad... lol. Ok, fine. Be sure to post your solution when you are done. Maybe then I'll post a C++ version.

Comment: Ok, so you say in your post you are trying to emulate C++, then when I point out that you can easily interweave C++ and your target language you say you hate it. Makes perfect sense. I guarantee a combination would end up a lot cleaner looking that this. Nevermind the fact that it will outperform it probably by an order of magnitude. But sorry I said anything, Dude.

Comment: Also, if I am using C++ for this I will have to rewrite my ENTIRE LIBRARY in C++ so, eh, no. C++ overloading may be able to tell `int` apart from `id` (Objective-C object) but it cannot tell `NSNumber *` apart from `CMVector *` because they are both `id` to C++. Thus a native Objective-C method is required. Since C++ helps nothing then why bother?

Comment: That's a better argument then 'linus doesn't like it.' I didn't know how far into the forest you had gone with types. Have you ever looked at boost? For things like this, it buts all other stuff I've ever seen to shame.. Don't get me wrong, I love O-C, but for something like matrix math, I'd use C++.